# wordpress breadcrumbs bug "giving styling class to some page and not giving it to other"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, breadcrumbs

i am using Rana theme in WordPress and i face a bug with breadcrumbs in some pages it works perfectly and other it works but with a style bug
[working breadcrumbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x89pn.png)
[style bug breadcrumbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z31v7.png)

ps:
while using  inspect it seems to give styling class to the working one and doesn't give the styling class to non working one

i searched every breadcrumb setting and search all over the web but i didn't find a clue about what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just fixed this by editing the theme breadcrumbs code
it was missing the url line in the breadcrumbs array

```
else if ( is_tax('ranna_recipe_category') ){
            
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ranna_recipe_category');
            echo "<script>console.log('" . json_encode($terms) . "');</script>";
            
                                     
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
             
                $draught_links = array();
                echo "<script>console.log('" . json_encode($draught_links) . "');</script>";
                
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $breadcrumbs[] = array(
                       //Adding this line solve th problem
                        'url'  => $home_url .  $term->slug,

                        'name' => $term->name,
                    );
                } 
            }
        }
```